# How to create nice shell command wrapper in Python

Tags: python, command, subprocess, wrapper, metaclass

I created special metaclass so I can have nice wrapper for programs/commands with first 'action' argument ( without dash(es) ). Especially svn, git etc. I don't want to use external tools for that purpose.

```
  import subprocess

  class CmdWrap(type):

      def __new__(mcs, name, bases=(object,), dict={}):
          dict['name'] = name
          return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)

      def __getattr__(self, name):
          def run_cmd(*args, **kwds):
              cmd = (self.name, name) + args
              process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         cwd=None)
              out = process.communicate()

              if process.returncode != 0:
                  raise Exception(cmd, process.returncode, out)
              else:
                  return out

          if name in self.__dict__:
              return self.__dict__['name']
          else:
              return run_cmd
```

What do you think ? Would prefer running you favourite command like that:

```
svn = CmdWrap('svn')
svn.ls('http://your_repository/')
```

Could be done better ? Or do you think it is misuse of metaclasses ? Tell me.

Comment: Why use a metaclass at all? Note that if this is *working code* that you think could be improved, it might be better on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/)? I think it's exactly what you want. If not, look at how they wrap shell commands.

The `Command` and `RunningCommand` classes (see the [`sh`](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py) repo) could be useful.

Comment: I stumbled upon it. Yes, but it is a little overkill, in case you would rather not use external library, I think there could be some better choice. Anyway, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend to take a look at [Plumbum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum)

```
>>> chain = ls["-a"] | grep["-v", "\\.py"] | wc["-l"]
>>> print chain
/bin/ls -a | /bin/grep -v '\.py' | /usr/bin/wc -l
>>> chain()
u'13\n'
```